# access index of struct item field in Golang

Tags: go

Is there any possibility to change character with some index in struct field if it is string?

I mean I can do such manipulations with string type:

```
func main() {
    v := "Helv"
    v[3] = "p"
}
```

How can I do same thing with struct fields? Below assignment doesn't work.

```
type ik struct {
    a int
    b string
}

func main() {
    f := ik{1, "Pasis"}
    fmt.Println(f.b)
    f.b[2] = "r"
}
```

Comment: No you cannot assign to v[3] at all.

Comment: Strings are immutable, `v[3] = "p"` is a compile time error.

Comment: String index expressions may not be assigned to (see the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)).

Comment: well. if it is not supported, can you advise me some technique which will help to achieve this task(replace some character in field of struct)?

Comment: strings are immutable, simply replace the string with what you want.

Comment: @JimB unfortunately, I do not know which string to be replaced. I mean for ex I'm getting struct from DB, Matching it's one field (string) with regex, if it has 5 letters and start with "A", i need to replace 2nd and 3rd letters with "*". Can you advise how to achieve this?

Comment: You create a new string which has the right content. Take a look at packages strings for helpful string functions and redo the Tour of Go once more for basics of the language.

Comment: If someone needs, I did it like this:

```

package main

import (
 "fmt"
)

type ik struct {
 a int
 b string
}

func main() {
 f := ik{1, "Pasis"}
 fmt.Println(f.b)

 a := []byte(f.b)
 a[2] = 'r'
 f.b = string(a)
 fmt.Println(f.b)
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As strings are immutable in Go, you need to reassign another string to the variable. You can achieve this with following slice trick,

```
chars := "Helv"
// To replace the character in i'th index,
chars = chars[:i] + "p" + chars[i+1:]
```

So, your program becomes,

```
type ik struct {
    a int
    b string
}

func main() {
    chars := "Helv"
    chars = chars[:3] + "p" + chars[4:]
    fmt.Println(chars)

    f := ik{1, "Pasis"}
    fmt.Println(f.b)
    f.b = f.b[:2] + "r" + f.b[3:]
    fmt.Println(f.b)
}
```

Go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/flERg0MVXLE